# How do I only print to the screen the coordinates of what the mouse is drawing on a canvas in Java?

Tags: java, canvas, coordinates

I am working on a program that allows the user to draw a on the canvas and the coordinates of what they drew are printed onto the screen.

My question is, If the mouse draws a line on the screen how do you print the coordinates for that line to the screen.

Comment: Please post your code, your question is *broad* in its current state

Comment: Java can be used with multiple GUI toolkits... JavaFX, Swing, or "other"...

Comment: What coordinates? If a line is drawn what do you expect to appear on the screen?

Comment: The user draws a line on the screen, how do I print the coordinates of that line to the screen?

Answer (score 2):

My idea on how to do that:

1. Create a [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html),
2. Add [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and a new `Layout`,
3. Add [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) or similar,
4. Decide how frequently you want to add new coordinates (as you can't do anything continuously),
5. Run a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) which will append the text in the `JTextArea` or similar with current coordinates.